# How to combine write characteristics and charcteristics notify using RXBluetoothKit for RxSwift

Tags: swift, rxiosble

I am trying to interface a BLE device using RXBluetoothKit for swift. All the data commands of the device follow the following sequence
1. write a command (writeWithResponse)
2. Read the response from notification (on a different characteristics)

The number of notification packets (20 bytes max in a notification packet) will depend on the command. This will be a fixed number or essentially indicated using a end-of-data bit in notif value.

Can this be achieved using writeValue(), monitorValueUpdate() combination?

Answer (score 2):

```
// Abstraction of your commands / results
enum Command {
    case Command1(arg: Float)
    case Command2(arg: Int, arg2: Int)
}

struct CommandResult {
    let command: Command
    let data: NSData
}

extension Command {
    func toByteCommand() -> NSData {
        return NSData()
    }
}

// Make sure to setup notifications before subscribing to returned observable!!!
func processCommand(notifyCharacteristic: Characteristic,
                    _ writeCharacteristic: Characteristic,
                    _ command: Command) -> Observable<CommandResult> {

    // This observable will take care of accumulating data received from notifications
    let result = notifyCharacteristic.monitorValueUpdate()
        .takeWhile { characteristic in
            // Your logic which know when to stop reading notifications.
            return true
        }
        .reduce(NSMutableData(), accumulator: { (data, characteristic) -> NSMutableData in
            // Your custom code to append data?
            if let packetData = characteristic.value {
                data.appendData(packetData)
            }
            return data
        })

    // Your code for sending commands, flatmap with more commands if needed or do something similar
    let query = writeCharacteristic.writeValue(command.toByteCommand(), type: .WithResponse)

    return Observable.zip(result, query, resultSelector: { (result: NSMutableData, query: Characteristic) -> CommandResult in
        // This block will be called after query is executed and correct result is collected.
        // You can now return some command specific result.

        return CommandResult(command: command, data: result)
    })
}

// If you would like to serialize multiple commands, you can do for example:
func processMultipleCommands(notifyCharacteristic: Characteristic,
                             writeCharacteristic: Characteristic,
                             commands: [Command]) -> Observable<()> {
    return Observable.from(Observable.just(commands))
        // concatMap would be more appropriate, because in theory we should wait for 
        // flatmap result before processing next command. It's not available in RxSwift yet.
        .flatMap { command in
            return processCommand(notifyCharacteristic, writeCharacteristic, command)
        }
        .map { result in
            return ()
        }
}
```

You can try above. It's just an idea how you could handle it. I tried to comment the most important things. Let me know if it works for you.